# Toggle post expansion in the mod queue

Tags: feature-request, moderation, moderator-tools

Posts in the mod queue are shown in an abbreviated form, which is great for keeping the list as short as possible.  If a mod needs to view the post to make a judgement, they can click on the post's abbreviated body to expand it with the full content (sans tags).

The problem is that, once expanded, you cannot collapse it.  Most of the time its fine, as the post isn't that long.

But sometimes you get a real long one.  And you have to scroll down to find the mod tools at the bottom of the post.  And then, once the post is dealt with, you have to hunt back up the queue to find the place where you left off.  It can be very annoying.

**Can we simply have the ability to toggle expansion of the post?**  As I click on the abbreviated post to expand it, can I also click on the expanded post to hide all but the first four or five lines?

Comment: Odd, I wonder who was against this idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I can see that it would be nice to hide away some huge mammoth of a post without reloading. Next deploy.